# GraphQL query filtering multiple relations

Tags: graphql, strapi

(From Strapi) I am trying to get all "acts" with a certain age (can return multiple) and with a certain place (can return multiple). I can't figure out how to filter that.
This is what I am trying in GraphQL-playground (works without the variables), but it says "Unknown argument "age" on field "Act.ages"." (and "place" respectively).

```js
query GetActs ($age:Int, $place:String) {
  acts {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        Title
        ages (age: $age) {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              age
            }
          }
        }
        places (place: $place) {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              place
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just ran into this same issue. I can't make out the error you're reporting, but here is what worked for me.

You can use `filter` at the collection level to drill down to nested fields for the corresponding `attributes`. This follows the GraphQL example at the bottom of this [Strapi resource on filtering nested fields](https://strapi.io/blog/deep-filtering-alpha-26).

### Solution

```
query GetActs ($age:Int, $place:String) {
  acts (filters: {ages: {age: {eq: $age}}, places: {place: {eq: $place}}}) {
    data {
      id
      attributes {
        Title
        ages {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              age
            }
          }
        }
        places {
          data {
            id
            attributes {
              place
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```